# CSS shopping cart Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling wit a piece of code.

Im trying to make my menu look like this

[image: Image of what I want]

but if I hover my mouse over the checkout button the drop down dissapears if I try to select a menu item. if i create a href it changes to the checkout button styling.

Secondly my dropdown menu wont extend to be the whole size, it stays in line with the checkout button.

My code http://jsfiddle.net/vaaljan/TNftc/

```
<div id="cart">
        <div id="cartText">You have 2 items in cart</div>
      <ul id="checkout">
        <li><a href=#>Go to checkout</a>
            <ul id=itemList>
                <li>
                <img style="float:left; padding-right:10px" src="images/item1.jpg" width="64" height="64" alt="Item1" /> 
                Lorem ipsum dolor<br />
                99:-<br />
                Read More</li>
                <li>
                <img style="float:left; padding-right:10px" src="images/item1.jpg" width="64" height="64" alt="Item1" /> 
                Dolor sit amet<br />
                99:-<br />
                Read More</li>
                </ul>
      </ul>
    </div></div>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBN1U.jpg):

Comment: You really shouldn't use inline CSS

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/TNftc/1/

Comment: Thank you so much.  and Yes I forgot I did that, it was part of my attempt to fix the cart!

Answer (score 2):

There was a 3px gap between the checkout button and the dropdown menu. So, while moving the cursor from checkout to the dropdown menu, Dropdown menu disappears.
So, I have reduced the 3px top margin in the list.

`ul#checkout li a{ }` selector selects all the anchor tag inside the list. But, we have to select only the first anchor tag. So, we can use `ul#checkout > li > a {  }` selector.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sriraman/TNftc/5/)